# Cannot install dependencies with NextJs and Python errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, sass

I've been trying to install dependencies for this template but every time but always get the same amount of errors.
I used both NPM and YARN, deleted all node_module, cleaned the cache, etc....
It seems like there's something wrong with my Python version but I'm not sure.

this is the link GitHub link the template: [nextjs-argon-dashboard](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/nextjs-argon-dashboard)

ERROR

```
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[-/4] ⡀ waiting...
[2/4] ⢀ node-sass
[-/4] ⢀ waiting...
error C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\node-sass
Output:
Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\bruno\\Downloads\\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@18.16.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:306:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\bruno\\Downloads\\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\bruno\Downloads\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\nextjs-argon-dashboard-master\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v18.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
```